# SQLite delete not actually deleting

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I am saving user selected data to. This data will be visible in a listview and if you long click on the data it will delete that item. This is working as I see the item disappear from the listview, but when I restart the application and all the listview items are brought back in from the database, everything that was deleted is coming back. I am using this statement:

```
public void deleteAlarmEntry(int pos){
        Log.i("Deleting item from pos: ", String.valueOf(pos));
        db.delete(MySQLHelper.TABLE_NAME, MySQLHelper.ID_COL + "='" + pos + "'", null);
    }
```

I can see the statement being called in the logs. Is there a better way to make sure that the statement is executing correctly? Is something wrong here?

Here is my removeItem method called in the MainActivity on long click of the listview item:

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
    alarmItemArray.remove(position);
    dataSource.deleteAlarmEntry(position);
    alarmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The dataSource.deleteAlarmEntry() calls the above database remove.

Also, on application startup I am bringing the entries into a temp arraylist and then parsing the time to get the adapter arraylist like so:

```
dataSource = new WeatherDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();

    ArrayList<AlarmEntry> alarmEntries = (ArrayList<AlarmEntry>) dataSource.getAllWeatherEntries();

    alarmItemArray = getTimeFromEntries(alarmEntries);

    alarmAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.activity_alarm_item, R.id.time, alarmItemArray);

    lv = (MyListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
```

Here is the database's getAllWeatherEntries:

```
public List<AlarmEntry> getAllWeatherEntries(){
    List<AlarmEntry> weatherEntry = new ArrayList<AlarmEntry>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(MySQLHelper.TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        AlarmEntry m = cursorToEntry(cursor);
        weatherEntry.add(m);
        Log.i("Get all weather entries", m.getTime());
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();


    return weatherEntry;
}
```

Comment: add here your full logcat, please.

Comment: 07-22 12:55:57.683: I/Deleting item from pos:(29438): 8

Comment: and are you sure that item was deleted also from database and not only from list for example?

Comment: It should be, does that logic look correct? Whats the easiest way to look at the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just passing everything from that item to your query.

In `OnContextMenuItemSelected` you will need to do something similar to the below; you will need to change the parameters of your `deleteAlarmEntry` to receive a string instead of an int.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
String selectedID;
// adapter is the Adapter from creating the listview
    selectedID = String.valueOf(adapter.getItemId(info.position));
    deleteAlarmEntry(selectedID);
    }
```

You will also need to modify the db.delete to return a number, ie `int result = db.delete()` per the function. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

EDIT:

you may want to use `OnItemLongClickListener` instead of `OnLongClickListener`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String id = String.valueOf(alarmAdapter.getItemId(position);
removeItem(id);
            }
    });
```

SECOND EDIT:
Try this for cursoradapter, i'd recommend using a simple cursor adapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

```
String[] from = new String[]{"time"}; //enter your time column name here
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.time};
Cursor cursor = db.query(MySQLHelper.TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_alarm_item, cursor, from, to);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I made some edits, I already have the position and this is being passed in fine.

Comment: you want the ID of the position not just the position, passing only the position will pass everything, which is why the logcat shows (29438): 8 and not just the ID from the database.

Comment: Ah, so where should this onContextItemSelected be added? In the mainActivity? And call this instead?

Comment: how are you populating the listview? are you using a cursor with cursor adapter or are you just populating an array list?

Comment: how are you calling the `removeItem`? EDIT Is it in `OnLongClickListener'

Comment: Yes, it is in the removeItem called from onLongClickListener

Comment: see my edit, you will want to use onitemlongclicklistener instead of onclick listener, this would go where you set your list adapter, however this may not work because your using an arraylist with your listview and not using a cursoradapter to populate the listview

Comment: I am getting "The method getItemId(int) is undefined for the type AdapterView<capture#1-of ?>" because it is an ArrayAdapter

Comment: On application startup, I bring the items into a temp array and then parse that temp array into the ArrayList<String> that have the time that will be used as the arraylist for the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: can you post the full output? the code should work as posted as alarmAdapter is an ArrayAdapter and getItemId is a method for ArrayAdapter

Comment: Oops, sorry I had AdapterView<?> alarmAdapter and it was using that instead of my actual alarmAdapter.

Comment: Is it okay to do: int newId = (int) alarmAdapter.getItemId(position);
    removeItem(newId);

Comment: Why do I need to pass a String?

Comment: because it returns a `long` and its easier to just convert it to string or use long if you wish

Comment: Would the phone's "back" button effect the deletion in the DB at all? Would this ruin the state in some way and return the items that were deleted?

Comment: And I am not using a CursorAdapter, are you hoping that the ID will come from the database?

Comment: The ArrayAdapter doesn't have any connection with the database.

Comment: it would be beneficial to use a cursoradapter to fill the list view as it is connected to the database and removing an item from the database will be much easier. Im afraid using an ArrayList/ArrayAdapter will create extra work to remove it from the database. Is there a reason you aren't using a CursorAdapter?

Comment: I was having trouble using the CursorAdapter of my <AlarmEntry> and then being able to parse the CursorAdapter to get the time that I want to use to display in my listview.

Comment: So I read all the entries in the database into an ArrayList of AlarmEntry then I parse each AlarmEntry to grab the Time and create an ArrayList<String> of the time so that is what I use for the ArrayAdapter on start up

Comment: That is why my removeItem() contains a removal from the array and a removal from the dataSource

Comment: check my edit, that should make the cursor adapter work, though it doesn't use your AlarmEntry, if you wanted to use that you would have to create a custom one.

Comment: Okay, so I went a bit of a different route. I added: long id = alarmEntry.getPos(); in deleteAlarmEntry in my datasource and I kept track of the alarm entries as well in an arraylist. I will need to clean this up in the future. But it was the ID like you were saying. Sorry for so many questions, but you seriously were a ton of help!

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
public void deleteAlarmEntry(int pos) {
    db.delete(MySQLHelper.TABLE_NAME, MySQLHelper.ID_COL + "=?", new String[]{pos + ""});
}
```